# Print o número mínimo da lista?

Tags: python-3.x

Tenho este código e não consigo que seja mostrado o número -1. Dá um erro:

> not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.

Pelo que vi por outros forums tem haver com a comparação de strings com inteiros. Como posso ultrapassar isto?

```
list1=[2,2, 'a', 31, int(-1), 'b']
list2=[1, 3, 40]
list1[len(list1):]=list2
list1.append(5)

print (len(list1))
print (sorted (list1[7:]))
print (min(list1))

print (list1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que a melhor maneira é ignorar o que **não for um número**.

Isso porque se o número menor tiver ponto flutuante a outra solução proposta vai ignorá-lo.

Em Python3 isso é muito fácil

```
import numbers
min([x for x in list1 if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)])
```

Faça este teste

```
list1=[2, 2, 'a', 31, int(-1), 'b']
list2=[1, 3, 40]
list1[len(list1):] = list2
list1.append(5)
list1.append(-3.0)

min([x for x in list1 if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)])
# Saída: -3.0

min(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), list1))
# Saída: -1
```

Comment: Uma alternativa é fazer: `min([x for x in list1 if type(x) in (int, float)])`

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter` para remover os valores não inteiros do seu `list`:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 'b']

result = min(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), list1))

print(result)
```

A função `filter` retornará todos os itens da lista através da avaliação do  `callback` passado, caso seja verdadeira a sentença.

Ou seja:

```
lambda x: isinstance(x, int)
```

Comment: Não aprendi essa função (filter) não existe outra maneira?

Comment: @Miguel mas `filter` não altera a lista original. Por isso não fiz isso.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters E se o menor número foi `-2.0`?